# How to insert Collate into Wordpress search query?

Tags: query, search

I want to improve my default Wordpress search query and add `COLLATE utf8_bin`. What is the best way to do this action? Should I edit *wp-includes/query.php* or manipulate with *functions.php* file from **themes** folder?

Comment: I told you - never ever touch the core. First, you will lose all your changes upon update. Secondly, with a very high probability, you will crush some functionality of WordPress. After your previous question, I tried to analyze by Xdebug the code related to the main WordPress query, and understand why COLLATE does not work. With no success so far, hopefully will find enough time in the next few days. Code is complicated there, with two passes in respect to caching plugins, with many conditions involved.

Comment: And I analyze code of the core not to edit it, by to find a proper hook usage which will solve the task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the following code to the `functions.php` of your theme (and it is better to make all modifications in [child theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes)):

```
add_filter( 'posts_search' , 'posts_search' );
function posts_search( $search ) {
    $search = str_replace( 'LIKE', 'COLLATE utf8_bin LIKE', $search );

    return $search;
}
```

It works. You can check it on my test site:

```
http://test.kagg.eu/?s=čėšū
```

returns one post, but

```
http://test.kagg.eu/?s=cesu
```

returns nothing.